# In R: Finding and Replacing part of a variable's name every time it appears in the script

Tags: r, replace, substitution

I am running the same piece of code on many variables in a data set. For example:

```
xPart1 <- d$xPart1

xPart1complete <- rbind(xPart1, A)
```

I was wondering if there was a way to replace every instance of `xPart` (even though it only occurs partially in variable names) with `yPart`.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Simran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `RStudio` then you can press `ctrl+F` and a bar will appear at the top of your script. Then you can write the part of the word that you want to replace and with what you would like to replace it with.

Moreover, there is an option where you can check the option `in selection`, by doing so, the replacement will take place only in the part of the code that you selected

Comment: @SimranParmar. No problem. You can mark your question as answered :)